# This is weird questions about if statement. My If statement doesn't work probably. why?

Tags: ios, if-statement, uitextfield

I have this simple if statement that check UItextfields if empty or not like this:

```
 if([UserID.text isEqualToString:@""] || [UserPass.text isEqualToString:@""]){
        UIAlertView *alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" 
                                                               message:@"Fields can not be empty." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alertsuccess show];
        [alertsuccess release];
    }
```

Here is problem, first time when I enter the view has these UItextfields. I test like this

- Both  UserID & UserPass are empty--->If statement works correctly.
- UserID is NOT empty & UserPass is empty ---> not working. It just skipped my if statement even though second condition is true.
- UserID is empty & UserPass is NOT empty --->If statement works correctly.

Now the interesting part is here,if I dont exit the view during the test. I check UserID is NOT empty & UserPass is empty again(test#2 above), then the of statement work correctly. 
If I exit the view during the test, then if statement act weird again.

Can anyone help me to point out what did I do wrong here?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use : if ([UserID.text length] > 0]) {

Comment: i think when textfield is empty it sets text property to nil (not to @"")

Comment: You are right. It set to nil. And the problem was In viewWillAppear, I set UserPass = nil; That is why it the IF statement acted weird. Thank you very much.

Comment: No it will be empty string if you don't put anything in the textfield, unless you specifically set it to nil, I tested it.

Comment: The problem is I set UserPass = nil in viewWillAppear. That's answer for weird acting of the IF statement. I changed the if statement like your suggestion. It worked perfect now.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like UserPass (or UserPass.text) is not set to what you think it is; it may be set set to nil, which would make isEqualToString on it to always return false. If you hadn't made it work occasionally, I'd say there's a disconnected outlet.

Comment: I did connect them two in IB.

Comment: @JHHoang Could you add the property declarations to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Wired. Did you check whether your UserID and UserPass are defined as IBOutlet and connected in the IB?

Comment: I did connect them in IB. Is this any relate to becomeFirstResponder?

Comment: No, that's just where you wanna put your cursor. I think the problem is either they don't connect correctly or their values got reset somehow. Not sure yet, but if I were you, I'll set up a break point, and monitor the value. Sorry that's the only thing i could say. Good luck

Comment: Thank you, I will let you guys know when I solve this weird thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try NSLog("bool value: %d", [UserID.text isEqualToString:@""] || [UserPass.text isEqualToString:@""]); before evaluating the IF-statement to see the Boolean value.

Comment: Bool Values are 1; 0 ;1 for the tests above